# Difference between SMPP simulator And SMPP server

Tags: java, smpp

When can I say my smpp simulator as smpp server.
Actually I found logica smpp simulator,can I configure it as a smpp server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simulator is a simply a working prototype, which is used only to demonstrate the functionality. Simulators are generally not designed/written for production use. A full fledged SMPP server should be able to confirm to the complete protocol specification. Also it should be able to handle desired number of concurrent requests/second.

The day your simulator turns into a SMPP node confirming to the specification and able to handle the desired load, then you can pronounce it as SMPP server.